# Running Python code in different processors

Tags: python, multicore

In order to do quality assurance in a critical multicore (8) workstation, I want to run the same code in different processors but not in parallel or concurrently.

I need to run it 8 times, one run for each processor.

What I don't know is how to select the processor I want.

How can this be accomplished in Python?

Comment: I think you ought to include the operating system(s) you are targeting.  Scheduling on CPUs is out of Python's purview for the most part ( neglecting calling out to the OS to do the scheduling of course ).

Comment: It's on Linux Fedora. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux with [schedutils](http://schedutils.sourceforge.net/), I believe you'd use [taskset](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html) `-c X python foo.py` to run that specific Python process on CPU `X` (exactly how you identify your CPUs may vary, but I believe numbers such as 1, 2, 3, ... should work anywhere). I'm sure Windows, BSD versions, etc, have similar commands to support direct processor assignment, but I don't know them.

Answer (score 3):

Which process goes on which core is normaly decided by your OS. On linux there is taskset from the schedutils package to explicitly run a program on a processor.

Python 2.6 has a [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module that takes python functions and runs them in seperate processes, *probably* moving each new process to a different core.